# In Bootstrap3, how can I make the carousel-caption have a background with 50% opacity?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I need my carousel-caption to have a background with opacity of 50%. I have tried the code below, but it does not work in IE11 or older. I have looked at the older posts on here about it, and none of those solutions work in IE.

I tried this:

```
.carousel-caption {
background: rgba(255, 184, 28, 0.5);}
```

and even this for gradient:

```
.carousel-caption {
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255, 184, 28, 1), rgba(255, 184, 28, 0.5));}
```

HTML:

```
    <!--START CAROUSEL-->
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="false">
  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="../../images/LD/desktop_hero1.png" alt="..." class="img-responsive">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        Text for caption 1 here.
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="../../images/LD/desktop_hero2.png" alt="..." class="img-responsive">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        Text for caption 2 here.
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="../../images/LD/desktop_hero3.png" alt="..." class="img-responsive">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        Text for caption 3 here.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>       
<!--END CAROUSEL-->
```

CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
.carousel-caption {
max-width: 100%;
width:100%;
background: rgba(255, 184, 28, 0.5);};
left: 0;
bottom: 0;
color:#000000;
}
</style>
```

**ANSWER:**
I needed to add this to the CSS:
filter: alpha(opacity=50);

Comment: That should work in IE11, have you tried other browsers? also, post your html.

Comment: It worked in Firefox, but not IE. I just added my HTML and CSS.

Comment: I just figured it out. I just needed to add filter: alpha(opacity=50); to my CSS.

Comment: @AshleyK answer yourself using a proper "answer" below

Comment: @WesFoster Done. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

All I needed to do was add the following style update:

```
filter: alpha(opacity=50);
```